# Can't install NVIDIA graphics driver for Optimus/Bumblebee configuration

Tags: linux, nvidia, optimus

I have followed the following steps to get Optimus/Bumblebee configuration running on Fedora 20 (fresh basic installation) on my brand new laptop (based on msi barebone MS-16GC).

I have listed all steps, very similar to [this link](http://forums.if-not-true-then-false.com/index.php/topic,595.0.html)

The end result has x not booting, I can boot to a terminal. I feel I am stuck at the last step, please help:

These are the steps I have taken

1) My BIOS does not support switching on/off the nvidia card
2) Fedora 20 was installed from live cd - kernel/software updated - kernel-devel and kernel-headers are installed, along with gcc-c++ and lshw. NVIDIA display driver version 331.20 is downloaded, but not installed yet. 
3) Subsequent current kernel: 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
4) lspci gives two devices of intrest

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] (rev a1)

lshw shows that the NVIDIA card uses nouveau

```
 *-display

        description: 3D controller
        product: GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M]
        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        version: a1
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
        configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
        resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff

*-display
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 06
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:43 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

In preperation of driver NVIDIA driver install

5) blacklist nouveau, by creating a file blacklist.conf in /etc/modprobe.d/ with the line blacklist nouveau

Reboot

mv /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r)-nouveau.img
dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)

Reboot

And in /etc/default/grub
I added rdblacklist=nouveau to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
Followed by the grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg command

Reboot the computer (just to be sure)

lshw now outputs the following - no sign of nouveau is disabled - device is UNCLAIMED.

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: 3D controller
                product: GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
 *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

6) Next I create a file in my home directory called .xinitrc containing following lines

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
exec gnome-session
```

7) Then I create a file in /etc/X11 called xorg.conf2
containing following data

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "no"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
#Comment to output using hdmi cable  
 Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

8) Time to install the drivers

/* I get stuck here */

Type chmod +x NVIDIA*
And then ./NVIDIA*

Next I move  xorg.conf2 to xorg.conf

This installs fine, but then all I get is a black screen, also when I type startx from command line.

Comment: This is not a question for [so]. You might get help on [su] or [unix.se]

Comment: This is actually best asked on ask.fedoraproject.org